# Apple IOS update 8.4 question

Tags: ios

I recently updated my iphone to ios 8.4  How do I shuffle my offline music the way I used to before the update ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you used to shuffle your music before, but apparently there is a way to restore the 'shuffle all songs' functionality present on earlier versions, if that is what you mean:

http://ios.wonderhowto.com/how-to/shuffle-all-songs-apples-new-music-app-ios-8-4-0162796/

(EDIT: The two methods in that page are:

- While a song is playing, use Siri and say "shuffle songs".
- Create a 'smart playlist' containing all your stuff, because you can still shuffle within a playlist.

)

Comment: That only shufles songs within the album  The old way shuffled from one artist to another.For example it could play a song by ABBA then the next song could be by Dr Hook.  Yes I could make a playlist but I have over 3000 songs on my phone.  How to I make my entire collection a playlist?  Let me know how I can tell Apple I am seriously dissappointed with them for screwing up my music on my phone.  Why try to fix something thats not broken.

Comment: But if you create a playlist with ᗅᗺᗷᗅ and Dr Hook in it, then shuffle within that playlist should work? If so, you could create a smart playlist that contained all your 1970s abominations, and it would happily throw in some David Soul as part of the shuffle, too :)